# Delphi CEF 4 not loading some sites

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded

I have a problem opening website
https://servicebox.mpsa.com/ other site working fine like google, youtube ........
I'M USING cef_74.1;
any ideas???

Comment: The best idea is that you tell us what error you get. "Not working fine" is not enough to help you.

Comment: it's just not loading, just a blank page, you can test it yourself

Comment: The obvious difference with "other site working fine" is that the page is protected by Basic auth.

Comment: Olivier, yes I agree with you, is there a way to open it with cef?

Comment: Why weaken a precise issue with phrases like "not loading" and "a problem"? If you request that website in a web browser it clearly asks for authentication credentials, and if one cancels it the result is [HTTP status 401](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_client_errors) - you must have seen/experienced that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That website is asking for a username and a password.

You need to use the TChromium.OnGetAuthCredentials event. If you already know the username and password then add this code in that event :

```
callback.cont(MyUsername, MyPassword);
Result := True;
```

If the user has to type the username and password then copy the browser, originUrl, isProxy, host, port, realm, scheme and callback parameters into class fields, set Result to True and send a custom Windows message to the main form to show a custom form where the user can type his/her credentials.

When the user enters that information and presses the OK button then call :

```
callback.cont(Username, Password);
```

If the user presses the CANCEL button then call :

```
callback.cancel;
```

Read this pages for more information about that event and the "callback" parameter:

- [TChromium.OnGetAuthCredentials](https://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefRequestHandler.html#GetAuthCredentials(CefRefPtr%3CCefBrowser%3E,constCefString&,bool,constCefString&,int,constCefString&,constCefString&,CefRefPtr%3CCefAuthCallback%3E))
- [Callback](https://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefAuthCallback.html)

CEF 74 is outdated. Please, consider using the latest [CEF4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi) version available at GitHub.

Comment: If it worked for you, you should mark the answer as accepted.